# list vector data on a jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

Hi I want to list data from a vector on my jsp file but the problem I have no error and nothing is listed I can't list the data passed can you find what's wrong thank you for your help.
the page load but 
JSP file

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.trajets}" var="trajet" varStatus="boucle">
<td><c:out value ="${trajet.dateTrajet}" /></td>
<td><c:out value= "${trajet.HeureTrajet}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${trajet.nbrPlace}"/></td>

</tr>
</c:forEach>

</tbody>
</table>
```

My servelt

```
public static final String TRAJET         = "AllTrajet";
public static final String SESSION_USER = "sessionUtilisateur";
public static final String VUE_FORM            = "/WEB-INF/AllTrajet.jsp";


public AllTrajet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    DataBase conn = new DataBase();

    Vector<Trajet> trajets = conn.listeTrajet();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    session.setAttribute(TRAJET, trajets);

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE_FORM).forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: When reaching the doGet method, does your `trajet` vector contains the data that you need ?

Comment: yes i had list it with system.out.print() and it contains data

Comment: What resources are you using to learn Java, JSP and Servlets? Vectors were abandoned more than a decade ago and these days it's very surprising to see them in "new" code. Are you sure that your learning resources are the most recent available and of good quality? I'd throw away all of it and check on Amazon.com for the latest on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not referring the Object.

You have to change the reference.

`<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.AllTrajet}" var="trajet" varStatus="boucle">`

Comment: How can I do it please

Comment: "AllTrajet", not "TRAJET"

Comment: Just replace the line `<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.trajets}" var="trajet" varStatus="boucle">` with the above line and check.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have typo error. In servlet key used is `AllTrajet` and in jsp its `trajets`.

In jsp try using:

```
<c:forEach items="${AllTrajet}" var="trajet" varStatus="boucle">
```

Also make sure that in jsp EL is enabled.